# How to manage socket connections for a chat server (Python) via sockets and select module

Tags: python, sockets, select, module

Sorry to bother everyone with this, but I've been stumped for a while now.

The problem is that I decided to reconfigure this chat program I had using sockets so that instead of a client and a sever/client, it would have a server, and then two separate clients.

I asked earlier as to how I might get my server to 'manage' these connections of the clients so that it could redirect the data between them. And I got a fantastic answer that provided me with exactly the code I would apparently need to do this.

The problem is I don't understand how it works, and I did ask in the comments but I didn't get much of a reply except for some links to documentation.

Here's what I was given:

```
connections = []

while True:
    rlist,wlist,xlist = select.select(connections + [s],[],[])
    for i in rlist:
        if i == s:
            conn,addr = s.accept()
            connections.append(conn)
            continue
        data = i.recv(1024)
        for q in connections:
            if q != i and q != s:
                q.send(data)
```

As far as I understand, the select module gives the ability to make waitable objects in the case of select.select.

I've got the rlist, the pending to be read list, the wlist, the pending to be written list, and then the xlist, the pending exceptional condition.

He's assigning the pending to be written list to "s" which in my part of the chat server, is the socket that is listening on the assigned port.

That's about as much as I feel I understand clearly enough. But I would really really like some explanation.

If you don't feel like I asked an appropriate question, tell me in the comments and I'll delete it. I don't want to violate any rules, and I'm pretty sure I am not duplicating threads as I did do research for a while before resorting to asking.

Thanks!

Comment: have you looked into Twisted Python ?  It does this out-of-the box - http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/#auto1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Note: my explanation here assumes you're talking about TCP sockets, or at least some type which is connection-based. UDP and other datagram (i.e. non-connection-based) sockets are similar in some ways, but the way you use `select` on them in slightly different.*

Each socket is like an open file which can have data read and written to it. Data that you write goes into a buffer inside the system waiting to be sent out on the network. Data that arrives from the network is buffered inside the system until you read it. Lots of clever stuff is going on underneath, but when you're using a socket that's all you really need to know (at least initially).

It's often useful to remember that the system is doing this buffering in the explanation that follows, because you'll realise that the TCP/IP stack in the OS sends and receives data independently of your application - this is done so your application can have a simple interface (that's what the socket is, a way of hiding all the TCP/IP complexity from your code).

One way of doing this reading and writing is *blocking*. Using that system, when you call `recv()`, for example, if there is data waiting in the system then it will be returned immediately. However, if there is no data waiting then the call *blocks* - that is, your program halts until there is data to read. Sometimes you can do this with a timeout, but in pure blocking IO then you really can wait forever until the other end either sends some data or closes the connection.

This doesn't work too badly for some simple cases, but only where you're talking to one other machine - when you're talking on more than one socket, you can't just wait for data from one machine because the other one may be sending you stuff. There are also other issues which I won't cover in too much detail here - suffice to say it's not a good approach.

One solution is to use different threads for each connection, so the blocking is OK - other threads for other connections can be blocked without affecting each other. In this case you'd need two threads for each connection, one to read and one to write. However, threads can be tricky beasts - you need to carefully synchronise your data between them, which can make coding a little complicated. Also, they're somewhat inefficient for a simple task like this.

The `select` module allows you a single-threaded solution to this problem - instead of blocking on a single connection, it allows you a function which says "go to sleep until at least one of these sockets has some data I can read on it" (that's a simplification which I'll correct in a moment). So, once that call to `select.select()` returns, you can be certain that one of the connections you're waiting on has some data, and you can safely read it (even with blocking IO, if you're careful - since you're sure there's data there, you won't ever block waiting for it).

When you first start your application, you have only a single socket which is your listening socket. So, you only pass that in the call to `select.select()`. The simplification I made earlier is that actually the call accepts three lists of sockets for reading, writing and errors. The sockets in the first list are watched for reading - so, if any of them have data to read, the `select.select()` function returns control to your program. The second list is for writing - you might think you can always write to a socket, but actually if the other end of the connection isn't reading data fast enough then your system's write buffer can fill up and you can temporarily be unable to write. It looks like the person who gave you your code ignored this complexity, which isn't too bad for a simple example because usually the buffers are big enough you're unlikely to hit problems in simple cases like this, but it's an issue you should address in the future once the rest of your code works. The final list is watched for errors - this isn't widely used, so I'll skip it for now. Passing the empty list is fine here.

At this point someone connects to your server - as far as `select.select()` is concerned this counts as making the listen socket "readable", so the function returns and the list of readable sockets (the first return value) will include the listen socket.

The next part runs over all the connections which have data to read, and you can see the special case for your listen socket `s`. The code calls `accept()` on it which will take the next waiting new connection from the listen socket and turn it into a brand new socket for that connection (the listen socket continues to listen and may have other new connections also waiting on it, but that's fine - I'll cover this in a second). The brand new socket is added to the `connections` list and that's the end of handling the listen socket - the `continue` will move on to the next connection returned from `select.select()`, if any.

For other connections that are readable, the code calls `recv()` on them to recover the next `1024` bytes (or whatever is available if less than 1024 bytes). Important note - if you hadn't used `select.select()` to make sure the connection was readable, this call to `recv()` could block and halt your program until data arrived on that specific connection - hopefully this illustrates why the `select.select()` is required.

Once some data has been read the code runs over all the other connections (if any) and uses the `send()` method to copy the data down them. The code correctly skips the same connection as the data just arrived on (that's the business about `q != i`) and also skips `s`, but as it happens this isn't required since as far as I can see it's never actually added to the `connections` list.

Once all readable connections have been processed, the code returns to the `select.select()` loop to wait for more data. Note that if a connection still has data, the call returns immediately - this is why accepting only a single connection from the listen socket is OK. If there are more connections, `select.select()` will return again immediately and the loop can handle the next available connection. You can use non-blocking IO to make this a bit more efficient, but it makes things more complicated so let's keep things simple for now.

This is a reasonable illustration, but unfortunately it suffers from some problems:

1. As I mentioned, the code assumes you can always call `send()` safely, but if you have one connection where the other end isn't receiving properly (maybe that machine is overloaded) then your code here could fill up the send buffer and then hang when it tries to call `send()`.
2. The code doesn't cope with connections closing, which will often result in an empty string being returned from `recv()`. This should result in the connection being closed and removed from the `connections` list, but this code doesn't do it.

I've updated the code slightly to try and solve these two issues:

```
connections = []
buffered_output = {}

while True:
    rlist,wlist,xlist = select.select(connections + [s],buffered_output.keys(),[])
    for i in rlist:
        if i == s:
            conn,addr = s.accept()
            connections.append(conn)
            continue
        try:
            data = i.recv(1024)
        except socket.error:
            data = ""
        if data:
            for q in connections:
                if q != i:
                    buffered_output[q] = buffered_output.get(q, b"") + data
        else:
            i.close()
            connections.remove(i)
            if i in buffered_output:
                del buffered_output[i]
    for i in wlist:
        if i not in buffered_output:
            continue
        bytes_sent = i.send(buffered_output[i])
        buffered_output[i] = buffered_output[i][bytes_sent:]
        if not buffered_output[i]:
            del buffered_output[i]
```

I should point out here that I've assumed that if the remote end closes the connection, we also want to close immediately here. Strictly speaking this ignores the potential for TCP [half-close](http://www.vorlesungen.uni-osnabrueck.de/informatik/networking-programming/notes/22Nov96/3.html), where the remote end has sent a request and closes its end, but still expects data back. I believe very old versions of HTTP used to sometimes do this to indicate the end of the request, but in practice this is rarely used any more and probably isn't relevant to your example.

Also it's worth noting that a lot of people make their sockets non-blocking when using `select` - this means that a call to `recv()` or `send()` which would otherwise block will instead return an error (raise an exception in Python terms). This is done partly for safety, to make sure a careless bit of code doesn't end up blocking the application; but it also allows some slightly more efficient approaches, such as reading or writing data in multiple chunks until there's none left. Using blocking IO this is impossible because the `select.select()` call only guarantees there's *some* data to read or write - it doesn't guarantee how much. So you can only safely call a blocking `send()` or `recv()` once on each connection before you need to call `select.select()` again to see whether you can do so again. The same applies to the `accept()` on a listening socket.

The efficiency savings are only generally a problem on systems which have a large number of busy connections, however, so in your case I'd keep things simple and not worry about blocking for now. In your case, if your application seems to hang up and become unresponsive then chances are you're doing a blocking call somewhere where you shouldn't.

Finally, if you want to make this code portable and/or faster, it might be worth looking at something like [`libev`](https://code.google.com/p/pyev/), which essentially has several alternatives to `select.select()` which work well on different platforms. The principles are broadly similar, however, so it's probably best to focus on `select` for now until you get your code running, and the investigate changing it later.

Also, I note that a commenter has suggested [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) which is a framework which offers a higher-level abstraction so that you don't need to worry about all of the details. Personally I've had some issues with it in the past, such as it being difficult to trap errors in a convenient way, but many people use it very successfully - it's just an issue of whether their approach suits the way you think about things. Worth investigating at the very least to see whether its style suits you better than it does me. I come from a background writing networking code in C/C++ so perhaps I'm just sticking to what I know (the Python `select` module is quite close to the C/C++ version on which it's based).

Hopefully I've explained things sufficiently there - if you still have questions, let me know in the comments and I can add more detail to my answer.